# Get Item selected after right click on context menu

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, contextmenu

How can I get the selected item from clicking a context menu bound to a listview control in WPF?

This is my markup:

```
<ListView Name="lvCustomerJobs">
    <ListView.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu>
            <MenuItem Header="Remove"
                Click="cmCustomerRemoveJob"
                Command="{Binding RemoveItem}"
                CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContextMenu}, 
                Path=PlacementTarget.SelectedItem}" />
        </ContextMenu>
    </ListView.ContextMenu>
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Status" Width="150" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Status}" />
            <GridViewColumn Header="Booked in by" Width="150" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding BookedInBy}" />
            <GridViewColumn Header="Date Required" Width="150" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding DateRequired}" />
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

This is my code behind:

```
private void cmCustomerRemoveJob(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var item = ((FrameworkElement)e.OriginalSource).DataContext as User;
    if (item != null)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(item.DateRequired +  " Item's Double Click handled!");
    }
}
```

But item IS null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should cast `sender` object to `MenuItem` and then use `CommandParameter` like this:

```
private void cmCustomerRemoveJob(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var item = ((MenuItem)sender).CommandParameter as User;
    if (item != null)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(item.DateRequired + " Item's Double Click handled!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay in my response. Was called away. This works thanks  so muhc :)

Comment: What is the point of extracting the `CommandParameter` property value from the `sender` object, when that value should already be set in the `e` object?

Answer (score 1):

I bind my ListView to a collection in the model and bind the SelectedItem to the model as well.

```
<ListView ItemSource="{Binding CustomerCollection}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCustomer}">
```

Then, my command method can reference SelectedCustomer as needed.

If this isn't ideal for some reason, I'd love to know!

Comment: Sorry for the delay in my response. Was called away. I tried this but it did not work. Item still null